# Pay Employee via WordPress

Tags: plugins

I’m looking for a system where the employer can pay their employee via WordPress (frontend). Basically my portal job site is only providing a part-time job. After the job finished, the employee can request a payment and then the employer will send the money via our site.

Is there any plugin have such capability?
I'm currently using WP Job Manager as the main system of my site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked extension "WC Paid Listings" on official website?

Link: https://wpjobmanager.com/add-ons/wc-paid-listings/

Comment: Hello Alex,
Thank you for reply. I don't think the extension would suitable for my need. The plugin is about for charge employer when posting a job, isn't?